# When a room is unfrozen, apply last activity of the room to the moderator who did it

Tags: feature-request, bug, chat, frozen-rooms

In the chat [Lobby](//chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms), each room is showing when the last message was posted, and by whom. All good.

However, I just noticed a weird case:

> [image]

I certainly did not post a message there an hour ago. More like 5 weeks ago, so the message is wrong and misleading.

I understand that showing "40 days ago" would also be awkward, so my suggestion is that in case of moderator action in the room (e.g. manual freeze or unfreeze) show the time of the action (as it's showing now), but attribute it to the moderator who actually did it.

**Update**: about 8 hours after posting this, I now noticed it has changed to  show "38d ago":

> [image]

Was something fixed? Cache? Black magic? Still, think it's awkward.